# "no one" vs "no one else"

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

Can anyone please tell me if I should use ***no one*** or ***no one else*** in the following sentence?

Here is the example:

- John is a very good friend of mine. **No one (else)** likes me more than he does.

I think **no one likes me more than...**  means **no human being (including john) likes me more than john does**. So I think I should use **else**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`No one` is correct. John can not like you more than John likes you therefore saying `no one else` is insinuating that **other than John**, no one likes you more. Therefore stating that John likes you more than John does, which is impossible.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me if I used "as" instead of "more than" then which one would you prefer, "no one" or "no one else"? Here is the example: No one (else) knows me as much as my Mom does.

Comment: Then I would say ‘No one else’ because John likes you as much as John likes you.

Comment: Is there anything else that needs answering as I see you have not asked another question or marked as answered.